# change the size of search box in navbar to it's original size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image: This is how my navbar looks]

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left navbar-input-group" role="search" name="basicSearch" id="basicSearch">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group" style="">
      <input type="text" id="users" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Customer ...">
      <span style="" class="input-group-btn">
     <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
     </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

but the actual size of the search box is this 
[image]

can someone suggest me how to change navbox input size to it's default

Comment: Dilkush, what have you tried before?

Answer (score 1):

add the following lines into your webpage

```
$w=document.getElementById("nav3").offsetWidth;

$("#navBarSearchForm input[type=text]").width($w/2);
```

it will change the length of your search box.

Answer (score 0):

Make the width of your input box `initial` and float the button to the `left`, so it is next to the input box.

```css
#users{
  width:initial;  
}

span{
  float:left;  
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left navbar-input-group" role="search" name="basicSearch" id="basicSearch">
 <div class="form-group">
 <div class="input-group" style="">
 <input type="text" id="users" class="form-control"       placeholder="Search Customer ...">
 <span style=""class="input-group-btn">
 <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
 </span>                            
  </div>
 </div> 
</form>
```

Comment: <form class="navbar-form navbar-left navbar-input-group" role="search" name="basicSearch" id="basicSearch">
 <div class="row">
 <div class="col-sm-12">
 <div class="input-group" style="">
  
 <input type="text" id="users" class="form-control"       placeholder="Search Customer ...">
 <span style=""class="input-group-btn">
 <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
 </span>                            
  </div>
</div>
 </div> 
</form>  use grid layout